# How to re-size an image inserted via <picture> tag?

Tags: css, html

I have inserted an image using the following HTML:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .showcase picture {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width:600px)" srcset="images/p1.jpg">


      <img src="images/p1mob.jpg" width=100% alt="Image 1" />
  </picture>

  <p> <a href="">OUR MENU</a> 
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to set the picture's width to 30% only when the min-width of the screen is 600px.

Adding the above CSS isn't doing anything. How do I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target the `img` rather than the `picture`:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .showcase picture img {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width:600px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/400x400">


      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" width=100% alt="Image 1" />
  </picture>

  <p> <a href="">OUR MENU</a> 
  </p>
</div>
```

Or set your `picture` to `block || inline-block` to enable sizing via `width`:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .showcase picture {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width:600px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/400x400">


      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" width=100% alt="Image 1" />
  </picture>

  <p> <a href="">OUR MENU</a> 
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for giving more than one way to achieve what I wanted.  Both of these worked and helped me understand the code better :)

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting wrong, when you write css always know who you're telling what to do, for this you need to say grap the [target right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjQWv.png)

and then write the css instructions [img selections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43sfp.png)

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .showcase picture img {
    width: 30% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width:600px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/400x400">


      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" width=100% alt="Image 1" />
  </picture>

  <p> <a href="">OUR MENU</a> 
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the `!important` ?

Comment: Just to make sure that it overwrites the inline code [width: 100%; ]

Comment: You don't need to do that.